# Capture Yarn job id when executed in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm implementing a shell script to run a yarn job after validating some conditions. I would like to check the yarn job status/progress once triggered by the shell script using its jobid. Any thoughts on how it can be done?

Since I cant get the jobid from the PID i'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The output of `yarn jar` will have a line with `Tracking URL` or `application_`. You could just grep the output for it

Comment: `yarn application -list` will give you list of active jobs, if yours has specific name you can grep it

Comment: I wish i could use this but. My script will be run multiple times in parallel. This means multiple application id's to track for.

Comment: My yarn job will have the same name for all instances. That is making it a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

it's easiest to save it in HDFS and you can refer that anytime:

```
    val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
    fs.create(new Path("PathWithFileName"), true).writeBytes(sc.applicationId)
```